# Google Analytics metric value with no dimension value

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Anylytics I have custom dimension and I want value of for example visits with no dimension value. For example, I have custom color dimension with dimensions red, green, yellow and i want number of visitors which were not in any of there colors. When I query with ga:dimension1 and metric ga:visitors, GA return only values for these three colors but no values out of dimension. Are there way how I can achieve this by query or analytics settings?

Thans for response.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you don't "attach" dimension value to those hits, then Google Analytics won't provide you with any numbers in the report.

**You would have to use some generic form, for example *NONE*.** Otherwise, the dimension itself won't be attached to that hit and thus, it will not be displayed in your reports.